# Principal Ideal Domain Basics.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, principal-ideal-domains

Let $R$ be a Principal Ideal Domain and $a,b,c,d$ elements in $R$, such that $ab-cd=1$.
I am trying to figure out why $Rb \cap Rd=Rdab+Rbcd$.

In case this is true, I am wondering weather it is enough to claim, that $ab-cd=u$ with $u$ a unit in $R$.

Comment: @YACP Why should I be unhappy?! Maybe I did something wrong or did'nt do what I were supposed to. I don't know what you mean...

Comment: @YACP Sorry for my earlier comment. I am new to this forum and didn't know how to accept an answer! But now I got it and will do it from now on!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x = mb = nd \in Rb \cap Rd$. Then

$$x = x\cdot 1 = x (ab - cd) = ndab - mbcd \in Rdab + Rbcd.$$

Conversely, $Rdab \subset Rbd \subset Rb \cap Rd$ and $Rbcd \subset Rbd \subset Rb \cap Rd$, so $Rdab + Rbcd \subset Rb \cap Rd$.

It would indeed work with $ab - cd = u$ for any unit $u$, you'd multiply by $u^{-1}$ then at some point.

The gist of it is that $ab - cd = 1$ says that $b$ and $d$ are coprime, as are $a$ and $c$, and that means $Rb \cap Rd = Rbd$ resp. $Ra + Rc = R$.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer. I actually dont see why $Rdab \subset Rbd$ holds.

Comment: If $s \in Rdab$ then $s = rdab$ for some $r \in R$, so $s = (ra)bd \in Rbd$

Comment: Who says, that $R$ is commutative?

Comment: @user121511 It's part of the definition of a principal ideal domain.

Comment: @R2D2 In that case, showing that $Rdab \subset Rd$ seems not so easy. At least, nothing obvious jumps out to me. I'll think about it, but I make no promises.